# Ansible regex filter

Tags: python, regex, filter, ansible

Got a set of tags called tags_json in the form of

```
 [u'03fb9e77138602b41feb8f667f04cc8998a1fd00', u'1575c845a43685b674f54c5cfccd2850c34502ff', u'v0.2.1']
```

and would like to get only the ones that point at a version i.e. v0.2.1 . That's why I created a regex and used the regex_search filter

```
- set_fact: 
release_tags: "{{ tags_json | map('regex_search','\\b\\v(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){2}[0-9]{1,3}\\b') | select('string') | list }}"
```

but while listing that I'm getting just empty strings with no match. Suppose the regex itself is fine but can't get proper result (list of tags starting with a "v" and x.y.z).

Comment: Do not escape a letter if you need to get it as a literal char, replace `\\v` into `v`.

Comment: of course ... worked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove any escaping symbol before `v` and use

```
r'\bv(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){2}[0-9]{1,3}\b'
```

Or, to match the whole string,

```
r'^v(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){2}[0-9]{1,3}$'
```

Note that `\v` matches a `\x0B` symbol.

Basically, watch out what you escape, some literal chars when escaped form a *regex escape sequence* and stop matching those chars literally. See [Python `re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> Most of the standard escapes supported by Python string literals are also accepted by the regular expression parser:
>
> `\a      \b      \f      \n`
>      `\r      \t      \u      \U`
>      `\v      \x      \\`